# Make only checkbox clickable in activeadmin boolean fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, boolean, activeadmin

Right now, the boolean fields in the edit forms in activeadmin are rendered so that clicking on the whole row where the checkbox is positioned can change the checkbox value. So not only on the checkbox and its label but also on all the space left and right to it.

But I want to make just the checkboxes clickable, not the entire line. How is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to active_admin.scss file

```
form fieldset > ol > li.boolean label {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

this will work then with just the checkbox and the text and not all the line for both sides.